# Assign a function to multiple variables in shorter way

Tags: javascript

I have the following random email generator in JavaScript:

```
getRandomEmail = function () {
    var strValues = "abcdefghijk123456789";
    var strEmail = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < strValues.length; i++) {
        strEmail = strEmail + strValues.charAt(Math.round(strValues.length * Math.random()));
    }
    return strEmail + "@mail.com";
};
```

And I want to generate as many random emails during the execution. I do this simply by calling the function and assigning it to the variable as many times as I want like so:

```
var randEmail1 = getRandomEmail();
var randEmail2 = getRandomEmail();
var randEmail3 = getRandomEmail();
var randEmail4 = getRandomEmail();
```

And so on, so the more emails I need, the uglier the code looks, and I was wondering if there's a short way of writing this?

EDIT:

I have 2 different .js files: randomMethods.js and Register.js

In randomMethods.js I have the function mentioned above, and in Register.js I have the following:

```
require('../helpers/randomMethods.js');
...
var getMultipleEmails = count => Array.from(Array(count))
    .map(() => getRandomEmail());
var emails = getMultipleEmails(1);
...
emailInputField.sendKeys(emails[0]);
```

I'm using Jasmine framework and Protractor.

Comment: you can create an array and push emails into array, and return array

Comment: something like `const emails = [...new Array(100)].map(() => getRandomEmail())`?

Comment: How do you use those variables? Chances are you only need to call `getRandomEmail()` at the time you actually need a new value rather than assign to an arbitrary number of variables

Comment: Since I'm still a novice to JS, I might need to have the "create an array and push emails into array" explained. I could call the function itself when I need a new value, but I have to re-use some of those random emails during the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them in multiple named variables, then there's no way to shorten this significantly.

Typically when you want a list of things like this, or when you want an unknown number of things, then it's good to have something like an `array`.

The code below shows a function to generate an array of random emails, and how you can access that data:

```js
var getRandomEmail = function () {
  var strValues = "abcdefghijk123456789";
  var strEmail = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < strValues.length; i++) {
      strEmail = strEmail + strValues.charAt(Math.round(strValues.length * Math.random()));
  }
  return strEmail + "@mail.com";
};

var getMultipleEmails = count => Array.from(Array(count))
  .map(() => getRandomEmail());
  
var emails = getMultipleEmails(5);

console.dir(emails);
console.log(emails[0]);
console.log(emails[1]);
console.log(emails[4]);
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try shortly, but it seems like it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @G.ILL Great, I hope it helps; if there are any problems at all, feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to help

Comment: `encountered a declaration exception (0.132 sec)
      - ReferenceError: getRandomEmail is not defined` this is what I'm getting. Any ideas?

Comment: That's basically saying that it hasn't been able to locate the function `getRandomEmail`; is that still present in the code you have?

Comment: Yes, but I've added the `var` in front of `getRandomEmail` as you suggested. Could it be the problem? I've tried without `var` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you able to provide the code you're using as an edit to this question? It may be something as simple as a spelling difference

Comment: I've added the code, maybe I have to export the function in a different way? But the way I had it before, worked without problems, but the code looked ugly

Comment: @G.ILL thanks for adding the code; it seems that it'll depend on what's exported from the file `randomMethods.js`; exporting varies depending on the environment you're in, but it's normally done in one of two ways: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export typically with `require` you need to assign it as a variable, for instance `var randomMethods = require('../helpers/randomMethods.js')`

Comment: Thank you! Importing with assigning it as a variable has fixed it! And the random method works as expected too, as well as the code looks much nicer now. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

```js
getRandomEmail = function () {
    var strValues = "abcdefghijk123456789";
    var strEmail = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < strValues.length; i++) {
        strEmail = strEmail + strValues.charAt(Math.round(strValues.length * Math.random()));
    }
    return strEmail + "@mail.com";
};



function generateNRandomeEmails(N){
  return [...Array(N).keys()].map((item)=> getRandomEmail() )
}

console.log(generateNRandomeEmails(5))
```